# Creating alias from subquery using QueryDsl

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, querydsl

My goal is to transform this `SQL query`:

```
select a.*, (select count(DOGS.DOG_ID) from DOGS where a.DOG_ID = 
DOGS.DOG_ID) cnt
from ANIMALS a
order by cnt desc ;
```

I create a `QueryDsl` query like this:

```
createQuery()
            .select(Projections.constructor(AnimalsDto.class, animal.animalId, animal.firstName,
                    Expressions.as(subQueryForDogsCount(dogs, animal), "cnt")))
            .from(animal).orderBy(new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.ASC, Expressions.asString("cnt"))).fetch();
```

And the `subQueryForDogsCount` is just:

```
JPAExpressions.select(dogs.count()).from(dogs)
            .where(dogs.dogId.eq(animal.dogId));
```

When I log that query I'm getting something like this:

```
[select 
animal.animalId, 
prospect.firstName,  
(select count(DOGS.dogId)
from DOGS dogs
where dogs.dogId = animal.dogId) as cnt
from ANIMAL animal
order by ?1 desc]
```

And when I want to execute it I'm getting a `NullPointerExpception`, I think the problem could be on the last listing at this point: `?1`. Why `querydsl` doesn't see this alias? Maybe is there any other way to create alias for it?